# How to simplify $\ln^2\left(x\right)+2 \ln x-3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I dont know how to simplify $\ln^2\left(x\right)+2 \ln x-3$

I dont know how to get $(\ln(x)+1)(\ln(x)+3)$

But I am stuck and don't really know how to do that.

I tried something like this: $2\ln x+2\ln x-3\:,\:\:2\ln\left(x\left(x-3\right)\right),\:2\ln\left(x^2-3x\right)$

Comment: I have no idea of what you're trying. In your work you show nothing actually related to differentiating the function.

Comment: Like Git, not sure what you want and also what you mean by derive (differentiate perhaps?). Also is it $2\ln(x) - 3$ or $2\ln(x-3)$ you mean?

Comment: for real.. i have no idea too :) i just need to find the derive of ln2(x)+2ln(x)−3  and i dont really know how..

Comment: i know that the answer is $\frac{2}{\:x}\left(2lnx\:+\:1\right)$

Comment: maybe he means simplify, or factor? Something like (log(x)-1) (log(x)+3) ?

Comment: you right rbm, how you get this one? :)

Comment: well use $y=ln(x)$ then you'll get $y*y+2*y-3$ and you can square it

Comment: This is your second very poorly asked 'derive' question in a short time. Stop posting these!

Comment: oh.. sorry.. but rbm, can you explain this answer please?

Comment: you shouldn't have accepted the answer below if you still dont understand it then

Comment: i dont understand how i can get (ln(x)−1)(ln(x)+3).. if i'll get this i know how to continue the derivate.. can you explain me only the the steps to get this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\ln^2(x)+2\ln{x}-3=(\ln(x)-1)(\ln(x)+3)$$

Comment: this is my problem! i dont know how to get this (ln(x)−1)(ln(x)+3)

Comment: If you substitute $y=\ln(x)$ it is a matter of simplyfing a quadratic equation, can you do that?